# Is there a way to get rid of deleted posts?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have deleted an answer to my own question. I knew that a deleted post can only be seen by the mods only. Although, I have not become moderator, I still can see my deleted answer. So how can I get rid of the deleted answer so that I don't have to see it?

Comment: You should post this type of questions on http://www.meta.stackoverflow.com. About this question, it's already asked o MSO under different title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can unfortunately. Deleted material is seen by moderators and the person who originated the post.

Comment: This, also that form of deletion is called a 'soft delete' as it is hidden from view.  Only SE employees can truly purge something from the site entirely.

Comment: @TylerShads, which I imagine they would only do for a very good reason.

Comment: Exactly, only if personally identifying information is placed in a post.